# How do I install Cacti 8.7i with PIA 3.1(Plug In Architecture) for 12.04 Server LTS?

Tags: 12.04, network-monitoring, cacti

I am planning to upgrade my current 9.04 server version to 12.04LTS server.

I've successfully backup and restore my Cacti version 8.7d to 8.7i that comes with the distribution.

However, the plugin patch installation for PIA 3.1 it is not working for only ubuntu.

Can you assist? or it's there a way to include Cacti 8.8a which is a stable version which comes with PIA 3.1 preinstalled.

regards,
thomas

Answer (score 1):

There has been a backport created for Cacti 0.8.8a for use in 12.0.4.

You can read the details about it in this Launchpad bug issue:[Please backport cacti 0.8.8a-3 (universe) from quantal to precise](https://bugs.launchpad.net/precise-backports/+bug/1018693)

To upgrade your Cacti installation from 8.7i to 8.8a, perform the following commands from a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:micahg/ppa
sudo apt-get install cacti
```

You should now be able to use the new Cacti Plugin Architecture.

The latest plugins can be downloaded from http://docs.cacti.net/plugins

In order to install the plugin, change to the directory where it was downloaded.
The default directory for cacti plugins is `/usr/local/share/cacti/plugins/`

Execute the following command:

`sudo tar -xvf <insert-plugin-file-name-here>.tgz -C /usr/local/share/cacti/plugins/`

The newly installed plugin should now be showing up in the cacti menu `Console --> Plugin Management`

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/40351#40351)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)