# How do I install Cacti?

Tags: server, network-monitoring, cacti

I'd like to use [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), but I'm not entirely sure how to install it.

I have a 10.04 Server that I'm installing this on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**This has been tested on 10.04 and 12.04 LTS.**

It's as simple as installing the `cacti` package.

To do that, run `sudo apt-get install cacti` and then follow the prompts. It will ask you to set a password for the root MySQL user.

[image: Install via the software center]

However, one thing that catches people is that it gives you a choice of which HTTP server you want to have it run under.

[image]

Unless you have good reason to do otherwise, select "Apache2" and hit enter.

Now it will go and install all the packages.

When it asks you if you want to have the database configured with dbconfig-common, select yes.

[image]

And then it will ask you for the password of the root user.

And then it will ask you to set a MySQL application password *specifically* for cacti.

Enter one in, and then repeat it in the confirmation dialog.

Once the install is done, head over to `your-ip/cacti` follow the prompts there.

[image]

Click next if you agree to the license.

Now you need to tell it what kind of installation - we're assuming you're doing a new install here, so just click "Next".

[image]

Now here is the important part.

It will try and find all the various tools it needs - by default, they should be all green, but if it isn't, you'll need to do some digging to find where that tool is.

[image]

Click next.

Now you're at the login screen. The default username is `admin`, and the default password is `admin` as well.

[image]

Now it will have a forced password change. Change your password to whatever you want it to be.

[image]

Hit next after that, and you're in!

[image]

Have fun with Cacti!

Comment: I have provided some additional information on upgrading to cacti version 0.8.8.a, which supports the Cacti Plugin architecture(PIA) [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138283/cacti-8-7i-pia-3-1-for-12-04-server-lts/223723#223723)

Comment: Thanks - followed this, script runs ok, but nothing seems to get installed under /var/www - any ideas?

Comment: @UpTheCreek it isn't installed under /var/www. it's installed in its own special place, I'm not entirely sure where.

Comment: Ah I see - I guess there must be something in apache config - I'll check, thanks.

Comment: apache auto configuration creates a symlink in `/etc/apache2/conf.d` to `/etc/cacti/apache.conf` (similar to how phpmyadmin does it) which is where you can find information about the cacti file locations - although you may be doing something wrong if you think you need to start editing these files ;)